# Get data displayed in a django admin change_list

Tags: django, django-templates, admin, changelist

I've got an admin change_list with a list of companies and thier addresses. I want to plot this onto a google map. I've got google maps coming up, and the right data displaying in the change_list, and i've copied out the change_lsit template so Im overriding it.

They problem is that I need to get the data from the page, which I assume is in the change_list object and put that into the javascript so I can plot the addresses onto the map.

But I havent been able to find any doco on the change_list object or how to get at the data displayed. Normally you can just do something like {% model.attribute %} and if I was able to do something like that and wrap it in a for loop that would be great.

So any idea about how to get at the data in a change_list?

Cheers

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two approaches.
One is to use an api call from javascript to get the data.  The other, which is what you are planning I think, is to pass the data from change_list into your template.  Here is an example (may be out of date for googlemaps, but will give you the idea).  It assume change_list has two fields lat and longt:

```
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.setUIToDefault();

        {% for location in change_list %} 
            var point = new GLatLng({{ location.lat|default:"0.0" }}, {{ location.longt|default:"0.0" }});
            map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point)); 
        {% endfor %}
  }
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for this. Although to be exact in the template change_list is cl , so just for somebody coming later you might want to change that. Thanks Again!!